# Laravel notification blade else statement not working

Tags: laravel, if-statement, notifications, laravel-8, laravel-blade

I'm trying to show user notification if data is found in notification table else show 'notification not found' on user notification blade but else statement isn't working. It only shows user notification if found and a blank page if notification not found in table.

```
<body>

    <main>
        @include('siteLayout.sidebar')

        <div class="wrapper">
            @include('siteLayout.header')

            <div class="main-container">
                <div class="main-header">Notifications</div>
                <div class="main-contents">
                    <ul class="notification-lists">
                        @foreach ($notifications as $notification)
                            @if ($notification != null)
                                @if ($notification->musicOwner == Auth::user()->id)
                                    <li class="notification unread"><span class="notification-icon">         
                                        <div>You have notifications</div>
                                    </li>
                                @else
                                    <li class="notification unread"><span class="notification-icon">         
                                        <div>You have no notifications yet</div>
                                    </li>
                                @endif
                                @endif
                        @endforeach

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>

</body>
```

Comment: So if they have no notifications would `$notifications` be empty? Also can there be null notifications in your `$notifcations` variable?

Comment: If you can query the `$notifications` object with only the logged-in user's notifications, then you can simply use an `if else` statement outside the `for` loop and show the notifications or the message.

Comment: What happens if you have no notifications whatsoever?  $notifications == null

Comment: @nikistag I don’t think I understand your question correctly but if user has no notifications then it is said to be null definitely.

Comment: @NotDavid yes if they have no notifications $notifications will be empty (null). I just don’t get why it doesn’t execute the else condition

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the $notifications isn't empty as the foreach isn't working. If you would like to show the message if the $notifications is empty make it work like this, with forelse:

```
<body>

    <main>
        @include('siteLayout.sidebar')

        <div class="wrapper">
            @include('siteLayout.header')

            <div class="main-container">
                <div class="main-header">Notifications</div>
                <div class="main-contents">
                    <ul class="notification-lists">
                        @forelse ($notifications as $notification)
                            @if ($notification != null)
                                @if ($notification->musicOwner == Auth::user()->id)
                                    <li class="notification unread"><span class="notification-icon">                                         <div>You have notifications</div>
                                    </li>
                                @endif
                            @endif
                        @empty
                          <li class="notification unread"><span class="notification-icon">         
                                <div>You have no notifications yet</div>
                          </li>
                        @endforelse
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>

</body>
```

Comment: I tried it just now, still shows the same empty page.